# Why is this Linq Query returning 3 identical rows from the same SQL view?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I have a simple view defined MSSQL 2008.  The view is defined as follows:

```
    SELECT     dbo.tblCompany.CompanyID, dbo.tblAccount.Carrier, SUM(ISNULL(dbo.tblLine.LineCharge, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(dbo.tblLine.FeatureCharge, 0)) 
                      + SUM(ISNULL(dbo.tblLine.AccessCharge, 0)) AS SumOfCharges
FROM         dbo.tblCompany LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tblCompany_Location LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tblAccount LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tblLine LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tblBill_Data ON dbo.tblLine.LineID = dbo.tblBill_Data.LineID ON dbo.tblAccount.AccountID = dbo.tblLine.AccountID ON 
                      dbo.tblCompany_Location.LocationID = dbo.tblAccount.LocationID ON dbo.tblCompany.CompanyID = dbo.tblCompany_Location.CompanyID
GROUP BY dbo.tblCompany.CompanyID, dbo.tblAccount.Carrier
```

Which returns data in the form of:

```
1    Carrier1          $70.00
1    Carrier2         $100.00
1    Carrier3         $150.00
3    Carrier2          $60.00
....etc
```

This works fine with an SQL select statement.

I have a VB linq query that just sets a where clause based on the CompanyID.

```
Dim expenses = From exp In Me.vw_CarrierExpenses _
                       Where exp.CompanyID = companyId _
                       Select exp

        Return expenses.ToList()
```

If I filter based on a CompanyID of 1, using the example data above, I get the first row 3 times:

```
1    Carrier1          $70.00
1    Carrier1          $70.00
1    Carrier1          $70.00
```

I must be missing something very simple here.  It always returns the correct amount of rows but the data is always identical. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep forgetting that LINQ needs to have a true unique primary key field in query model.  I added the following 'fake' primary key to my view by adding:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dbo.tblCompany.CompanyID) As 'CarrierExpenseID'
```

to my view fields and then adding this as my primary key in my view model.